# How to read from STDIN on Hacker Rank code challenge in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Just had this problem for a tech interview. Took me a good 25 minutes before I found out how to get the input for my method. The is the gist of instructions they give for how to use their platform:

> The first stdin will be a integer that explains how many more lines are left.

Use `n = gets.to_i`

```
(0...n).times do |i|
  data = gets
  ##do stuff with data
end
```

Edit: For the people who thinks `gets` works, it didn't. when `n = gets`, n = nil

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Is this a Ruby problem or a HackerRank problem?

Comment: "gets didn't work" is not much of a problem description, is it? It works, unless there is something special going on.

Comment: You'll get `nil` when there's no more input. As always, [read the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-gets).

Comment: @tadman On their platform they told me the first stdin was an integer to dictate how many lines were left, which gave me a 1. The second `gets` that I did yield nil. What do you make of that?

Comment: If the first line yields two billion, what are the odds someone's actually going to type in that many? Plan for the best, prepare for the worst, and the worst here is you didn't get enough input because STDIN was closed.

Comment: @tadman I don't get the hostility of this community. I ran into a problem with HackerRank during a code challenge for a job. Solved it. Posted an answer here to my own problem. And now I got people telling me that I'm wrong. I'm confused.

Comment: It's not hostility but frustration. Remember, you're not the only one asking questions like this, you're one of thousands, and when you see the same thing over and over again it's easy to get sarcastic, snippy, or be really snarky. Ruby's documentation is something you *must* at least skim, and whenever you're using a method, consult the documentation specific to that. Many methods are counter-intuitive, there's no other way to understand them than to do your homework and try things.

Comment: The problem with your question is it doesn't really say what the problem is, doesn't define what *should* happen, and doesn't show a whole lot of effort to solve it. Posting to Stack Overflow is not something you do after twenty five minutes. It's something you do after an hour when you've read the documentation, when you've tried a dozen different approaches, and when you still have some confusion. Be clear about the *input* and *expected output* of your program, something omitted here much to everyone's frustration. Guessing what your code does is not fun.

Comment: "which gave me a 1" - aha! So it __does__ work? This means that the problem is not with `gets` but elsewhere. Perhaps, input data is set up to not provide subsequent data, or your code messes `gets` up, or something else. Given your claim that `STDIN.read` works, I'd like to bet that your code breaks gets somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `data = STDIN.read` for single line inputs.

And for multi line inputs, do

```
STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |a|
   puts a
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `gets` should work as well. You know, same as in regular ruby scripts.

Comment: If that worked, I wouldn't have posted here. Nor would I be pulling teeth when I had to do it.

Comment: As a note, `$stdin.readlines` will do the splitting for you. The [Ruby `IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html) class is unusually feature complete compared to most programming languages and offers a whole host of utility methods like this.